# Adjust jsonSerializer time zone

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, json

When I developing an app I have tested that `jsonSerializer` works fine, but then I copied it to production server it gives +2 hours to any time that goes thru `jsonSerializer`. So, how can I adjust time zone the `jsonSerializer` uses?

Comment: Have you tried `ToUniversalTime()` ?

Comment: How can I try it? Where should I type it?

Comment: Just tried it. Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: I prefer to use only utc time on the server side. Javascript can do utc-local convert (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to adjust the timezone for your date before you run the jsonSerializer.  You could adjust the time zone in your date by first setting it to UTC time. Then adjusting it with a TimeSpan like this:

```
        var date = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        var timeZoneAdjustment = new TimeSpan(0, -4, 0, 0);
        var timeZoneDate = date + timeZoneAdjustment;
```

Hope that helps..